# Hibernate session ID

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I'm working on large enterprise application that has many hibernate calls to database. I want to track down which session opened and which is closed.

So is there anything in hibernate we can get unique ID of that session or something else. Basic idea is to track down the session execution time. I checked many profiler but its not giving the proper output.

Comment: Did you find a way how to get this unique ID ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `session.toString()` to display the session id and it's status, open or close.

Answer (score 0):

What about the hashcode of the Hibernate session?

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.identityHashCode(session)` to find memory address and then you can figure if it's using same session in other method or not.

Comment: This appears to be different every time we call it, not unique to the session

Answer (score 0):

What about `getSessionIdentifier()` 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/internal/AbstractSessionImpl.html